# Why are new nodes in a D3 force directed graph not showing up consistently?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, directed-graph

I've been working with d3 for a while now in an attempt to create an interactive ecosystem explorer tool that maps out relationships between species. Recently I've tried adding a feature that lets users show or hide species (nodes) in the force directed graph. I've tried following other examples and although the code works - it only works inconsistently.

For some reason, when I add back a node, it sometimes isn't visible. The graph moves as if the node is added but then it doesn't show up. I have the feeling that it is adding it but then the node is being hidden again in the force.on("tick") code but have no idea why. I've posted the relevant code below and would really appreciate any ideas! The toggleNode function determines whether a node should be shown or hidden - basically just splicing or adding to the nodes array. I keep the data in an array called dataset that stores a flag to indicate whether a node is visible or not.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.gravity(.05)
.distance(100)
.charge(-100)
.size([w, h]);

var nodes = force.nodes(), links = force.links(); // arrays to hold data

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);         

force.on("tick", function() {

vis.selectAll("circle.node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

vis.selectAll("line.link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

});

function restart() {

// UPDATE nodes
var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});

// ENTER new nodes
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return groupColors[(d.group)-1]; })
        .style("stroke","fff")
        .style("stroke-width",1)
        .on("mousedown", function(d) {
            clickNode(d);
            })
        .call(force.drag);

// REMOVE deleted nodes
var nodeExit = node.exit().remove();

force.start();
}

// Add the nodes and links to the vis
function createVis(json) {

    dataset = json; // store data in global

    for (var i = 0; i < dataset['nodes'].length; i++) {
        // fill node info
        nodes.push(dataset['nodes'][i]);
    }

    restart();  
}

// Remove node and associated links.
function toggleNode(nodeKey,eol_id) {

    console.log(nodeKey + ': ' + eol_id);

    var tLabel; // value for toggle label

    if ( dataset['nodes'][nodeKey]['isHidden'] == 0 ) {

        // node is visible, so hide it
        tLabel = 'Show';
        for( var k=0; k<nodes.length; k++ ) {
            if ( nodes[k]['eol_id'] == eol_id ) {
                nodes.splice(k, 1); // remove this node
                break;
            }
        }
        dataset['nodes'][nodeKey]['isHidden'] = 1;
        console.log('node removed: ' + nodeKey);

    } else {

        dataset['nodes'][nodeKey]['isHidden'] = 0;

        nodes.push(dataset['nodes'][nodeKey]);

        tLabel = 'Hide';

    }

    $('#primary_title_toggle').html('&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick="toggleNode(' + nodeKey + ',\'' + eol_id + '\')">' + tLabel + '</a><br>');

    restart();

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that I need to set the x,y coordinates for a node that is added back? Are these nodes not visible because they are being positioned off the visible graph?

Comment: in general what you say is true :) good luck! p.s. look at my posts and you can find some tricks related to force directed layouts

Comment: I've done some more experimenting like examining the node's properties before and after it's hidden and then re-shown. Everything seems to be there and the x,y coords appear to be correct (that is, within the graph's visible scope). There's even a space in the graph where you'd expect to see the node but it's just not visible. I can use other nodes to push it around - confirmed when re-examining it's x,y coords. So I'm perplexed. Any ideas on how to make it visible again?

Comment: try posting an example using jsfiddle, tributary, blocks or something similar...it's a strange behaviour what you're describing in there, so I doubt many would be able to help just by reading your description of what happens :{

Comment: Thanks for the advice paxRoman. I've finally created a simplified jsFiddle version that demonstrates the problem. When you click on one of the nodes, a "hide" link will show up below the graph (you might have to scroll down a bit to see it). When it's hidden, "hide" changes to "show" which in turn is supposed to push the node back onto the array "nodes" and then re-display. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/holmesjtg/2jd8Z/10/

Comment: It looks like this might be the problem: "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")" (in the on "tick" method). Is it because it is trying to move a newly created node?

Comment: short answer is this: basically your entire tickFunction is wrong...you are right... what you should do there is something along these lines...you need a function that will calculate the virtual positions for the nodes and when you call the tick method it will use those virtual attributes to set x,y,width,height of each node inside the viewport...(only inside the viewport) - in your case it's outside..that is why you don't see it on the screen...take a look at x,y coordinates for your reinserted node...

Comment: take a look at this if you want to keep the nodes inside the viewport: http://bl.ocks.org/1129492 (please notice how it updates both cx and cy ???)

Comment: hope this is enough to help you solve it...unfortunately I will not be available until next week (going to a conference for few days...)...if the hints are not enough, hopefully someone else will step in to clarify those points...